# Aurelia customAttribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, integration, aurelia

I have a problem with customAttribute. I want to use it to plug in jquery-ui datepicker. Idea taken from here: http://www.danyow.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-aurelia/

However it looks like it is not working at all. I have tried to debug the application and it looks like attached@datePicker.js is not fired at all. However the file itself is being requested from the server. The worst thing is that I had it working yesterday evening, but today morning ...

I have created simple example in my fork of skeleton application: https://github.com/Exsilium122/skeleton-navigation
so it is ready to be cloned and run for troubleshoot.

The most important two files:

---

welcome.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./resources/datepicker"></require>
  <input id="myDate" datepicker="datepicker" value.bind="timestamp | dateFormat"/>
</template>
```

---

datepicker.js

```
import {inject, customAttribute} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'jquery-ui';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css!';

@customAttribute('datepicker')
@inject(Element)
export class Datepicker {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached = () => {
        console.log("attached Datepicker");
        $(this.element).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
        }).on('change', e => fireEvent(e.target, 'input'));

    }

    detached = () => {
        console.log("detached Datepicker");
        $(this.element).datepicker('destroy').off('change');
    }
}

function createEvent(name) {
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent(name, true, true);
    return event;
}

function fireEvent(element, name) {
    var event = createEvent(name);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

---

and the console is clean:

> DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-binding@0.16.1.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-binding@0.16.1.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-resources@0.16.1.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-resources@0.16.1.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/history-browser@0.9.0.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/history-browser@0.9.0.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-router@0.17.0.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-router@0.17.0.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/event-aggregator@0.9.0.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/event-aggregator@0.9.0.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin resources/index.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin resources/index.
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:46 INFO [aurelia] Aurelia Started
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://localhost:9000/dist/app.html ["nav-bar.html", "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"]
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://localhost:9000/dist/nav-bar.html []
>   aurelia-logging-console.js:38 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for http://localhost:9000/dist/welcome.html ["http://localhost:9000/dist/resources/datepicker"]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`attached = () => {` needed to be changed to `attached() {`, as discussed in the gitter.

Corresponding changes were required for the `detached` method.

This question can be closed- the OP got the issue resolved in the aurelia gitter.

Answer (score 3):

just did a:

- clone from your repo
- npm install jspm
- npm install
- jspm install -y

and guess what. it works :)

http://imagebin.ca/v/2KV4cFzITHtX

Comment: btw. using chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 m on windows

Comment: thank you for your effort. I had been fighting with this problem for couple of hours, so I have posted the question on stack and also tried gitter. Then Jeremy Danyow helped me. I was so happy that I have forgotten to go back to stack and close the question. Therefore I am sorry for wasting your time. Once more thank you for your effort.

It worked because I have corrected the error and committed to the repo.